# Radio button request parameter handling

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript

Somewhat related to this post: [How to catch selected radio button with requestParameter?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211748/how-to-catch-selected-radio-button-with-requestparameter)

I have 5 subscription options via radio button on a cloudpage.  Since the attribute name is shared, I cannot use the `requestparameter` function to change the bool field on the data extension through `UpsertDATA` function.

What's the best way to handle radio options through a formSubmit to ampscript?

```
%%[
set @send_all = requestparameter("send_all")
set @weekly = requestparameter("weekly")
set @bimonthly = requestparameter("bimonthly")
set @answer = requestparameter("option")

if @answer == "send_all" then 
        set @send_all = "true"
        set @weekly = "false"
        set @bimonthly = "false"
elseif @answer == "weekly" then 
        set @send_all = "false"
        set @weekly = "true"
        set @bimonthly = "false"
elseif @answer == "bimonthly" then 
        set @send_all = "false"
        set @weekly = "false"
        set @bimonthly = "true"
endif

 set @response = UpsertDATA(@de, 1, "subscriberkey", "send_all", @send_all, "weekly", @weekly, "bimonthly", @bimonthly)

]%%

<html>
    <form id="EA" name="EA" method="post" action="#">
       <input type="hidden" name="_subscriberkey" id="_subscriberkey" value="%%= v(@subKey) =%%" />   
       <input type="hidden" name="Unsubscribed" id="Unsubscribed" value="%%= v(@unsubscribed) =%%" />
       <input type="hidden" name="Submitted" id="Submitted">

        <input type="radio"  name="option" id="send_all" value="send_all"  />
        <label for="send_all" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please send me all email communications</label>
        <input type="radio"  name="option" id="weekly" value="weekly"  />
        <label for="weekly" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Once a week</label>
        <input type="radio"  name="option" id="bimonthly" value="bimonthly"  />
        <label for="bimonthly" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Twice a month</label>

        <input type="button" id="Update" class="Btn" value="SUBMIT" onClick="formSubmit();" /> 
    </form>
</html>

<script>
document.getElementById("send_all").checked = %%= v(@send_all) =%%;
document.getElementById("weekly").checked = %%= v(@weekly) =%%;
document.getElementById("bimonthly").checked = %%= v(@bimonthly) =%%;

function formSubmit(){
     var error = '';
     //Reset Error Messages to be hidden
     var array = document.getElementsByClassName("Error");
     for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {          
         array[i].style.display ='none';             
     };     

     //validation if Not Unsubscribed

     //If no error, then submit for update
     if (error == ''){
       document.getElementById("Submitted").value = 'True';       
       document.forms["EA"].submit();
     }else{
       //alert(error);
       document.getElementById("Submitted").value = 'False';
       return false;
     }
   }; 

</script>
```

Comment: can you share the radio button code you are using? It usually is easier to advise and troubleshoot with related code provided.

Comment: Simplifying and just doing a form post to itself, the `requestparameter("options")` is 100% accurate - displays only the selected value. I would check your JS submission function. Also not sure what you are doing with the `document.getElementById("send_all").checked = %%= v(@send_all) =%%;` as you cannot include SSJS and AMPscript in the same script tag.

Comment: Doesn’t this form post to itself already? Or do I need to remove the #?

Comment: I removed your JS validation scripts and changed the input `type="submit"` and `action=""` in form to simplify and verify just the requestparameter part. I believe having the action set to # should keep it on page still as well though.

Comment: @Gortonington Removed validation & changed `action` & `type`.  The requestparameter still needs to come from the `option` var name with accompanied if/else statements?  Or will the requestparameter pick up on the var ID and carry a bool?

Comment: I think I was misunderstanding what you were asking. See my answer below. I think that should provide the info you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your question now. What you would want to do is the following to collect and correctly assign your radio button values in your upsert:

```
%%[  
  set @subscriberkey = requestparameter("_subscriberkey")
  set @answer = requestparameter("option")

  set @send_all  = "false"
  set @weekly    = "false"
  set @bimonthly = "false"

  if @answer == "send_all" then 
        set @send_all = "true"
  elseif @answer == "weekly" then 
        set @weekly = "true"
  elseif @answer == "bimonthly" then 
        set @bimonthly = "true"
  endif

  set @response = UpsertDATA(@de, 1, "subscriberkey", "send_all", @send_all, "weekly", @weekly, "bimonthly", @bimonthly)

]%%
```

What you were doing was very close and would have kinda worked, but the radio parameter passes the value of the selected radio button, not true/false. To account for that:

1. First what I do is set ALL options to false, so that all the 'non-selected' ones don't need to be changed inside the conditional each time.
2. Write a conditional checking `@answer` for specific values and then setting the corresponding AMPscript var to "true" (can also set it to `= 1` to signify true for boolean).
3. Then you do your upsert that will change all values to a single true and rest false - according to the value selected in the form

Finally, if you were looking for a way to 'preselect' the current choice they had in this form, you can do the following:

```
%%[ set @sendall_selected = Lookup(@de, "send_all","SubscriberKey", @subscriberkey)
    set @weekly_selected = Lookup(@de, "weekly","SubscriberKey", @subscriberkey)
    set @bimonthly_selected = Lookup(@de, "bimonthly","SubscriberKey", @subscriberkey)
]%%
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="send_all" value="send_all" %%=IIF(@sendall_selected, "checked", "")=%% />
    <label for="send_all" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please send me all email communications</label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="weekly" value="weekly" %%=IIF(@weekly_selected, "checked", "")=%% />
    <label for="weekly" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Once a week</label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="bimonthly" value="bimonthly" %%=IIF(@bimonthly_selected, "checked", "")=%% />
    <label for="bimonthly" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Twice a month</label>
```

Basically this does a lookup of the value of your 3 options and sets a corresponding AMPscript var with true/false.  Then inside each of your inputs for the radio button I added in an IIF that will add in 'checked' if the value of that AMPscript var is true, making this one the 'preselected' button.