# Save radio button value into a variable using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm quite new AMPscript, the problem I'm facing is I want to store the radio button value into a variable then I want to display that variable please someone help me.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JavaScript Radio Button</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form
      id="dashform"
      action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%"
      method="post"
    >
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="reason_1" id="reason_1" />
        <label for="reason_1">I never signed up, or didn't realize I had signed up, for your email list.</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="reason_2" id="reason_2" />
        <label for="reason_2">Your content isn't relevant to me.</label>
      </div>
      <p>
        <button id="btn">Select your option</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/360791/edit) your question to add how this is not working (e.g., *exact* error text, *exactly* how it is misbehaving). *(Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center where, among other things, it says that your question should include, 'A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help).')*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Noor In order to capture the value of the radio button into a variable use below AMPscript snippet -

```
%%[
Set @Radio = requestparameter("option")
]%%
```

And to display this value you can use - %%=v(@Radio)=%%

Refer to this answer - [Radio button request parameter handling](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248615/radio-button-request-parameter-handling?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you it's working